# Soap 1.1 endpoint already registered on address test/myService

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, cxf, apache-camel

I have cxf and jwx published soap webservices, for which i wanted to integrating them into apache camel . I was trying to run a simple example to get routEntryPointService in as my entry point for camel. Here is the config file in spring.  When i try to deploy it in tomcat, i get an error Soap 1.1 endpoint already registered on address test/myService,at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.addListener(SoapBindingFactory.java:863)   please help me what am i doing wrong.

If i donot add cxf end point entry and camel entry, my services gets deployed successfuly. I am using cxf version 2.5.0.fuse-70-084  and camel version 2.9.0.fuse-70-084

Here is my configuration file.

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.connecture.exemplar.group" />
<bean id="groupDao" class="com.connecture.exemplar.group.daos.impl.GroupDaoImpl" />
<bean id="group" class="com.connecture.exemplar.group.service.impl.GroupImpl" />

<bean id="groupProxyFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="com.connecture.exemplar.group.service.Group" />
    <property name="address" value="http://localhost:8181/exemplar/Group?wsdl" />
</bean>
<bean id="groupClient" class="com.connecture.exemplar.group.service.Group"
        factory-bean="groupProxyFactory" factory-method="create" lazy-init="true" />
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="tryWebService" address="abc/ws"
        serviceClass="com.connecture.exemplar.group.integration.services.RouteEntryService">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO" />
        <entry key="setDefaultBus" value="true" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
<camel:camelContext trace="true">
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="tryWebService" />
        <camel:to uri="bean:routeEntryRequestProcessor" />
        <camel:to uri="bean:groupClient?method=findGroup" />

        <!-- <camel:to uri="bean:routeExitResponseProcessor"/> -->

    </camel:route>
```

Comment: You are trying to publish two different end point interfaces on same end point url, thats why this error is coming.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually the problem was i have previously <jaxws:endpoint id="groupService" implementor="#group"
  address="/Group" /> this end point defined for it, now i added camel end point too. Now  how can i make a single end point only in such a case.

Comment: Sorry, No idea how to do that in camel, i had got this error during my jax ws implementation while creating multiple bindings on single endpoint.

Comment: The exception services address is test/myService, can you double check it?

Comment: Yes. it is test/myService , which is defined in bean as cxf endpoint as  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="tryWebService" address="test/myService"
        serviceClass="com.connecture.exemplar.group.integration.services.RouteEntryService">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO" />
        <entry key="setDefaultBus" value="true" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>